# How to diagnose a system that freezes seemingly at random?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, freeze, troubleshooting

I am currently attempting to repair a laptop that experiences total system lock ups at random intervals, with a frequency of every few days.

*Total lock up here is defined as no response to user input - Ctrl+alt+delete, no task manager, no Alt + F4, no smooth shutdown, display in a frozen state, no recovery if left alone*

In this case, I am not asking for suggestions as to the cause, (as much as I appreciate any input offered) - I am asking for general advice in ***how to identify*** the cause of freezing, such as tools, logs and programs that may be able to trace the problem.

---

While the system in question here is a Windows 10 laptop, I believe it may be worth including wider suggestions for other operating systems and their versions, as future readers of this question might benefit from this.

Comment: Verify the problem isn't memory by running memtestc86, verify the HDD health is reported as being healthy, determine if it happens in a minimal configuration

Comment: Perform a RAM diagnostic with the windows memory diagnostic utility and with MemTestx86+, check the smart stats and perform `chkdsk` on all drives. if you have any unusual devices with potentially suspect drivers, try uninstalling them.